# Not able to get value from the dynamically generated drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**Problem**

I've 2 diff drop down select box. First select box is static whereas the other is dynamically generated according to the value selected in first select box. The values are getting generated properly but when I try to display the value of second select box it only display the first option's value, even if selected 3rd or 4th option. Please see code and example below:

**Javascript Code**

```
             function wpPopulate(){
                $('#win_parameter').empty();
                var classes = document.getElementById('noOfClasses').value;//total number of classes

                var percent = (100/classes);//to get a percentage for single class
                //console.log("1 class: "+percent+"%");
                //Define Variables
                var wpOptions = '';
                var dd = '';

                for(var i=1; i<=classes; i++){
                    dd = parseFloat(percent*i).toFixed(2)+"% ("+i+" class)";
                    wpOptions += '"'+parseFloat(percent*i).toFixed(2)+'": "'+dd+'", ';
                }
                wpOptions = "{"+wpOptions.substr(0, (wpOptions.length-2))+"}";
                wpOptions = $.parseJSON(wpOptions);

                var selectValues = wpOptions;

                $.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
                     $('#win_parameter')
                         .append($("<option></option>")
                         .attr("value",key)
                         .text(value));
                });
            }
```

**HTML Code:**

**(Select box 1)**

```
<select name="noOfClasses" id="noOfClasses" onChange="wpPopulate();">
    <option value="1" selected="selected">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
```

**(Select box 2)**

```
<select name="win_parameter" id="win_parameter">
</select>
```

**Example:**

When selected **5 classes** in first select box the options come in second select box are as follows. When I select anything apart from 20% it still displays as 20%, example 60%. Any help or guidance will be much appreciated!!

```
<select name="win_parameter" id="win_parameter">
   <option value="20.00">20.00% (1 class)</option>
   <option value="40.00">40.00% (2 class)</option>
   <option value="60.00">60.00% (3 class)</option>
   <option value="80.00">80.00% (4 class)</option>
   <option value="100.00">100.00% (5 class)</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Looks fine. Please check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NavinKrishnan/V459k/)

Comment: Works fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/ge253/1/

Comment: @Navin This functionality is working fine mate, what is not working fine is when u select a option from 2nd select box anything apart from option 1.. than it'll still show you the value of first option. Please wait, I'm adding it to fiddle and than you'll better understand it!!

Comment: Hey guys sorry for wasting your time, while putting on fiddle I got another idea and manage to get around the problem!! Much appreciate your time :-)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bhats1989/6db4w/1/